# Removing Data Below A Line In A Scatterplot (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

So I had code that graphed a 2dhistogram of my dataset. I plotted it like so:

```
histogram = plt.hist2d(fehsc, ofesc, bins=nbins, range=[[-1,.5],[0.225,0.4]])
```

I wanted to only look at data above a certain line though, so I added the following and it worked just fine:

```
counts = histogram[0]
xpos = histogram[1]
ypos = histogram[2]
image = histogram[3]
newcounts = counts #we're going to iterate over this

for i in range (nbins):
    xin = xpos[i]
    yin = ypos
    yline = m*xin + b
    reset = np.where(yin < yline) #anything less than yline we want to be 0
    #index = index[0:len(index)-1]  
    countout = counts[i]
    countout[reset] = 0
    newcounts[i] = countout
```

However, I now need to draw a regression line through that cut region. Doing so is not possible (AFAIK) in plt.2dhist, so I'm using plt.scatter. Problem is I don't know how to make that cut anymore - I can't index the scatterplot.

I have this now:

```
plt.xlim(-1,.5)
plt.ylim(.225, .4)

scatter = plt.scatter(fehsc,ofesc, marker = ".")
```

and I only want to retain the data above some line:

```
xarr = np.arange(-1,0.5, 0.015)
yarr = m*xarr + b
plt.plot(xarr, yarr, color='r')
```

I've tried running the loop with some variations of the variables but I don't actually understand or know how to get it to work.

Comment: So did I understand this correctly, you want a scatterplot of some data and a line through the data and then you want all the points below the line removed? Or possibly in a different color?

Comment: Hello! Your first interpretation is correct - I want all data below the line removed because I want to do further analysis on the data above the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a `mask` for your data before you plot and then just plot the data points that actually meet your criteria. Below an example, where all data points above a certain line are plotted in green and all data points below the line are plotted in black.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#the scatterplot data
xvals = np.random.rand(100)
yvals = np.random.rand(100)

#the line
b  = 0.1
m = 1
x = np.linspace(0,1,num=100)
y = m*x+b

mask = yvals > m*xvals+b

plt.scatter(xvals[mask],yvals[mask],color='g')
plt.scatter(xvals[~mask],yvals[~mask],color='k')
plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this [image: scatterplot with line]

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

If you want to create a 2D histogram, where the portion below the line is set to zero, you can do that by first generating the histogram using `numpy` (as an array) and then setting the values inside that array to zero, if the bins fall below the line. After that, you can plot the matrix using `plt.pcolormesh`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#the scatterplot data
xvals = np.random.rand(1000)
yvals = np.random.rand(1000)
histogram,xbins,ybins = np.histogram2d(xvals,yvals,bins=50)

#computing the bin centers from the bin edges:
xcenters = 0.5*(xbins[:-1]+xbins[1:])
ycenters = 0.5*(ybins[:-1]+ybins[1:])

#the line
b  = 0.1
m = 1
x = np.linspace(0,1,num=100)
y = m*x+b

#hiding the part of the histogram below the line
xmesh,ymesh = np.meshgrid(xcenters,ycenters)
mask = m*xmesh+b > ymesh
histogram[mask] = 0

#making the plot
mat = plt.pcolormesh(xcenters,ycenters,histogram)
line = plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.show()
```

The result would be something like this: [image: histogram with part below line removed]

Comment: Helped a bunch! I already have the 2d histogram, I just needed to get the scatterplot to work. :)