# Find all points below a line on a map

Tags: python, matplotlib, computational-geometry, cross-product

In order to draw a path between two points on a map with many points (almost two thousand), I use the following function:

```
def path_between_cities(self, cities_with_coordinates, from_to):

        from matplotlib.lines import Line2D     

        # coordinates from chosen path
        x = [int(from_to[0][2]), int(from_to[1][2])]
        y = [int(from_to[0][1]), int(from_to[1][1])]

        #create line
        line = Line2D(x,y,linestyle='-',color='k')

        # create axis
        x_ = np.array((0,2000))
        y_ = np.array((0,6000))

        plt.plot(x_,y_, 'o')

        for item in cities_with_coordinates:
            name = item[0]
            y_coord = int(item[1])
            x_coord = int(item[2])
            plt.plot([x_coord], [y_coord], marker='o', markersize=1, color='blue')
            plt.axes().add_line(line)

        plt.axis('scaled')
        plt.show()
```

My goal is to extract all points (coordinates) which are found below the drawn line.

I know that you can do this using the [cross product of vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Given a large number of vectors, what would be the most efficient way of achieving this in the context above?

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with matplotlib or plotting. You have an array of points and a line defined by two points. This is a typical computational geometry problem. It can be solved using NumPy alone (since you use it, anyway).

Comment: did I say the question was dependent on `matplotlib` or `plotting`?

Comment: You did - by tagging it with `matplotlib`.

Comment: it refers to matplotib, hence the tag. In the actual question, I use the word 'context', and that refers to matplotlib. anyway, sorry to have misguided you, sir.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44062109/2454357) helps. It might actually be a duplicate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each cross product operation is still `O(1)`. You can run the below function for all the points and see which of them are below, bringing it to a linear time check.

```
def ccw(a,b,c):
    """ Returns 1 if c is above directed line ab else returns -1"""
    return (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (c.x - a.x) * (b.y - a.y)
    #a and b are the vertices and c is the test point.
```

Unless you have some other information about the points, you would have to check each point to see if it below a particular line.